# Show additional attribute on product page when logged in (magento 1.9)

Tags: magento-1.9

I would like to show an additional product attribute on the product page in the same place as the rest, but only if I'm loggged in as a certain customer group.

So put simply I need to show an additional attribute on the front end when logged in as a certain customer group.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance,

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy this file

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

here

```
app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml
```

And replace these code

```
<?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

With These

```
<?php 
    $excludeAttributeOnLogin = array('country_of_manufacture'); // add all attribute which don't want to show for guest user
    $isLogedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn(); // Add our condition here and assigned true or false 
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): 

        if(!$isLogedIn && in_array(trim($_data['code']), $excludeAttributeOnLogin)){
            continue;
        }
        ?>
        <tr>
            <th class="label"><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
            <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to check customer is logged in or not

```
 <?php 
        if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
            //not logged in
        }else{
            // logged in
        }
    ?>
```

put your code to print attribute value in logged in block